# Finding highest path of DEM or contours file within area using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, elevation, contour, cost-path

I would like to create a polyline from one specified point to a target point. In between, I'd like to the vertices to fall on the highest point of elevation of that Y coordinate.

Essentially, this will be the highest path for that area - or highest profile for this extent.

Has anyone had luck doing this in ArcGIS Desktop?

Haven't been able to find a tool for this yet.

Comment: if you have a dem/tin and a profile/path then FME can give you the highest points/path see https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1372/converting-point-cloud-xyz-data-to-a-dem.html

Comment: Hi Mapperz, I am trying to create the profile/path from the DEM that goes through the highest points from point a to point b, so I don't think that method will work...

Comment: You could inverse the DEM and find the flow path... I'm taking that you want the path to be contiguous and not jump all over the DEM if there's a higher cell well away from the path on another ridge. For your inverse calculate (DEM maximum) - DEM to keep the numbers positive. Do you have a set of 'start' points you want to find the path from?

Comment: Hi Michael, I think inverting the DEM is a good idea but I am not sure how to do that. Can you elaborate a bit more please? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have spatial analyst? If so use Subtract http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005m000000mn000000 first value is statistical maximum (plus a small amount if you like to avoid negative values) of the DEM the second parameter is the DEM. If you don't have spatial analyst you can use GDAL_Calc http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html to invert or QGIS raster calculator https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html as viable alternatives.

Comment: I do have Spatial Analyst but I don't see a tool called Subtract.

Comment: Inverting the surface model and generating a flow line will give you a steepest path from point a to point b assuming point a is in the flow path downhill from point b.  It sounds like you want to traverse the highest ground from a to b.  Have a look at the cost path tool in the Spatial Analyst toolbox.  If I remember, there was a good tutorial on cost path surfaces via the ESRI Virtural Campus.  Basically it will cost more to travel downhill and less to travel uphill.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @GBG](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230298/finding-highest-path-of-dem-or-contours-file-within-area-using-arcgis-desktop#comment364347_230298):

> Inverting the surface model and generating a flow line will give you a
>   steepest path from point a to point b assuming point a is in the flow
>   path downhill from point b. It sounds like you want to traverse the
>   highest ground from a to b. Have a look at the cost path tool in the
>   Spatial Analyst toolbox. If I remember, there was a good tutorial on
>   cost path surfaces via the ESRI Virtual Campus. Basically it will cost
>   more to travel downhill and less to travel uphill.